# Storing and Retrieving Data in Session using Spring MVC

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

Want to save User information in session and want to get that back from session using Spring MVC 3.
Can any one give an example

But this is giving an exception

org.springframework.web.HttpSessionRequiredException: Session attribute 'user' required - not found in session

Comment: Can you post the code you are using to write and retrieve User data?

Comment: @SessionAttributes("user") I used for the controller @RequestMapping(value = "/login", method = RequestMethod.POST)
 public String login(@ModelAttribute("user") User theUser,
   BindingResult result, Model model) and adding the model.addAttribute("user",loggedInUser) and in retrieve method public String showDashBoardPage(@ModelAttribute("user") User LoggedInUser Model model) { System.out.print("The User is "+loggedInUser.getUserName())}